# ラズパイ上のMonoDevelopでC#ソースをビルドできません

Tags: c#, raspbian

ラズベリーパイにMonoDevelopをインストールし、ＷindowsPCのVisualStudio2017で作ったC#のプログラム(GUI)をプロジェクトごとフォルダでコピーしたところ、 MonoDevelopでソースをビルド(コンパイル)できません。
どうしたらいいのでしょうか。

ちなみにビルドするとMonoDevelopで以下のエラーメッセージが出力されます。

```
331　
インポートされたプロジェクト
“/home/pi/,cache/MonoDevelop/7.0/MSBuild/1068_1/Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets”
が見つかりませんでした。
<Import>宣言のパスが正しいかどうか、およびファイルがディスクに存在しているかどうかを確認してください。(MSB4019)
```

ライン入力で`cd`と`ls`を使って調べたところ、フォルダ「1608＿1」(ビルドするごとにこの数値は変化します)内に「Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets」は見つかりませんでした（似た名前のファイルはたくさんありました）。
（C#では「using System？」などNet.Frameworksのライブラリが読み込まれてないようです。）

ところで、すでにＷindowsPCでビルドした実行ファイルはラズパイで動作します。
大まかにＷindowsPCのVisualStudioでプログラムを作り、細かいデバッグをターゲットマシンであるラズパイ上のMonoDevelopで調整したいのです。

なお、ラズパイは産業向けのＣＭ3＋(32ＧＢ)とCMIOの組み合わせです。
ラズビアンは10(buster)です。

Comment: 関係は無いですが、もしダメそうだったらリモートデバッグを試してみては？[ラズパイにmonoをインストールしてVisual Studio 2017からC#アプリをリモートデバッグする](https://qiita.com/narista/items/8bf1f85e499bc723af0c), [remote debugging (windows -> linux) #188](https://github.com/mono/debugger-libs/issues/188)

Comment: リモートデバッグでビルドしてみましたが、結果は全く同じでした。

Comment: 英語版記事に付いた回答の紹介先を見ると、MacOSやUbuntu向けは解決したけどRaspbianやArchLinuxではまだ取得出来ないということですかね。[mono/mono#14875](https://github.com/mono/mono/issues/14875), [mono/mono#16639](https://github.com/mono/mono/issues/16639), [mono/monodevelop#8304](https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/issues/8304)

Comment: ここ [monodevelop raspbian not able to build a project #8304](https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/issues/8304#issuecomment-544977546) で古い mono に入れ直して対策できたというコメントが付いてますね。